# Basic algebra with sympy: keep coefficients and variables together

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to use sympy for some basic algebra and physics. When defining an equation such as

```
import sympy as sy
g,h = sy.Symbols("g h")
v = sy.sqrt(2 * g * h)
```

the equation v gets expanded to

```
v = sqrt(2) * sqrt(g * h)
```

there a way to specify that the coefficient "2" should not be factored out from
under the square root and the term under the sqare root is kept as "2 * g * h"?  The reason I want to do this is that the underlying physics and the derivation of a resulting equation are sometimes much clearer to see if the relevant coefficients are not factored out.

Another example would be something like calculating the arc lenght in an equation like

```
phi = sy.symbols("phi")
r = sy.symbols("r")
a= r * phi
```

for the double of an angle

```
phi = sy.pi / 4
```

as in

```
a = r * (2 * phi)
```

which gets collected to

```
a = r * sy.pi / 2
```

when

```
a = r *  2 * (sy.pi / 4)
```

might be clearer to show how the result was obtained.

Comment: Did you try powsimp() ?  http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html

Comment: I don't think powsimp() is what I'm looking for. It seems to do the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to specify that the coefficient "2" should not be
>   factored out from under the square root and the term under the sqare
>   root is kept as "2 * g * h"?

Yes, just create a `Pow` object (power raise) with the optional parameter `evaluate=False`:

```
>>> Pow(2*g*h, S(1)/2, evaluate=False)
  _______
\/ 2*g*h
```

That is, `2*g*h` gets raised by `S(1)/2` (one half). Automatic evaluation during the object construction is disabled by `evaluate=False`.

Comment: This is basically what I want, but when using the resulting object for further calculations (e. g. when doing

    a=Symbol("a");
    b = a * Pow(2*g*h, S(1)/2, evaluate=False),

b will be "a * sqrt(2) * sqrt(g*h)". Is there a way to suppress automatic evaluation (semi-)permanently?

Comment: Yes, you can completely disable evaluation by importing global_evaluate from sympy.core.evaluate, then setting global_evaluate[0] = False

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll either use  global_evaluate with a context manager or do something along the lines of "two_gh= Symbol('2gh'); foo=sqrt(two_gh)" and finally doing "foo.subs({two_gh:2*g*h})" - which is a bit of a hack, but seems to at least get some decent output for the intermediate steps.